# Sort by in mongodb field contains an array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in which I store data in below format I want to apply sort by in below collection.

```
{
"job_count" : [ 
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
    ]
},
{
"job_count" : [ 
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
    ]
},
{
"job_count" : [ 
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
        ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
    ]
}
```

i want data to be like as below

```
{
    "job_count" : [ 
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
        ]
    },
    {
    "job_count" : [ 
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e"),
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
        ]
    },
    {
    "job_count" : [ 
            ObjectId("58eb607531f78831a8894a3e")
        ]
    }
```

my complete query is

```
Jobs.aggregate(
            {"$match"  : $condArray},
            {"$unwind" : { path: "$mytradesmen.hired", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
            {"$lookup" : {
                        "from":"users",
                        "localField":"mytradesmen.hired",
                        "foreignField":"_id",
                        "as": "user_details"
                    }
            },
            {"$unwind": { path: "$user_details", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},

            { "$sort" : {"job_count":-1}})
```

Can anyone help me figure out the query i should modify to get the expected result,
please let me know in case of any further detail required i will edit my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator to create an extra field that holds the count of the elements in the array and then **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** on that field:

```
Jobs.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "count": { "$size": "$job_count" },
            "job_count": 1
        }
    },
    { "$sort" : { "count": -1 } }
])
```

Comment: what if i want this to be conditional actually by using project i will have to mention all the field i need to display which will be quiet time taking is there any way to make this condition optional

Comment: There is a better way if you have MongoDB version 3.4 and greater which has the [**`$addFields`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) operator, equivalent to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.